# How to apply this schematic of a CNN?

Tags: cnn, pytorch

I'm trying to apply a model [from a paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7146316/) to my problem, however I get very poor results (R² = 0.1 for regression). I think I don't understand the schematic drawing of the CNN used in the paper. Could you please help me understand it?

Step 1:
[image]

This is the schematic of what the authors call convp-20(1x2x2). As input they are using an image with several channels, each representing a principal component. Is my implementation in pytorch correct?

```py
step1 = nn.Sequential(                    # in_dim = (n, n_components, 15, 15)
    nn.Conv2d(
        in_channels=n_components,
        out_channels=n_components*20,
        kernel_size=2,
        groups=n_components
    ),                                    # dim = (n, n_components*20, 14, 14)
    nn.BatchNorm2d(n_components*20),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.MaxPool2d(2),                      # dim = (n, n_components, 7, 7)
)
```

Step 2:
[image]

The next step in the paper is called convp-20(20x2x2). This comes immediately after convp-20(1x2x2) and is repeated 3 times. Is my implementation correct? I'm particularly unsure about this step.

```py
step2 = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Conv2d(
        in_channels=n_components*20,
        out_channels=n_components,
        kernel_size=2,
        groups=n_components
    ),                                 # dim = (n, n_components, 6, 6)
    nn.BatchNorm2d(n_components),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.MaxPool2d(2),                   # dim = (n, n_components, 3, 3)
)
```

Final step:
[image]

As final layer they use this. I think my code should be correct?

```py
step_final = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Flatten(),
    nn.Linear(in_features=20*3*3, out_features=1)  # I want to use regression instead of classification, therefore output dim = 1
    # Also the input dim is dependant on how many times the convp-20(20x2x2)-step has been applied
)
```

If you want to read the paper, you can [find it here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7146316/) and look under the section "4. 2D-CNN with Principal Components."

Comment: I think I found the reason for my confusion: I was assuming they were using multiple principal component maps as input to their CNN, but it seems they were using only the first one.